# Show audio player only in specific post type

Tags: audio

I have a code that automatically auto-plays audio, I found it on this site and it works. The issue there is that it auto-plays it site-wide. Is there a way to only enable the autoplay for specific post types? The code is below.

```php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_67108_autplay_music' );

function wpse_67108_autplay_music( $content )
{
    if ( ! is_singular() )
    {
        return $content;
    }

    $audio_files = get_children(
        array (
            'post_parent'    => get_the_ID(),
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'audio'
        )
    );

    $audio = '';

    if ( $audio_files )
    {
        $id   = array_pop( array_keys( $audio_files ) );
        $url  = wp_get_attachment_url( $id );
        // add a 'controls' attribute to enable controls
        $audio = "<audio src='$url' controls autoplay loop></audio>";
    }

    return $audio . $content;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested, but it seems to me that you could simply replace the:

```
$audio = "<audio src='$url' controls autoplay loop></audio>";
```

with

```php
$autoplay = is_singular( 'your_post_type' ) ? 'autoplay' : '';
$audio = "<audio src='$url' controls $autoplay loop></audio>";
```

I.e. We use the `$autoplay` variable to store the `autoplay` attribute, and if the current page is the single page for your post type (`your_post_type`), then we set the variable value to `autoplay`.

But if you want to ***add/enable** the audio player* only on your custom post type pages, then you just need to change the `is_singular()` in your code to `is_singular( 'your_post_type' )`. Something like:

```php
function wpse_67108_autplay_music( $content )
{
    if ( ! is_singular( 'your_post_type' ) )
    {
        return $content;
    }

    // ... the rest of your code here.
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a million

Comment: Glad it worked for you! And would you mind marking my answer as "correct"? ( just tick the check-mark next to my answer :) )

Comment: Hello, please I just ran into another error. I need the player to be totally removed except on the post type I specify. It currently doesn't auto play on any other post type except the one specified but I want it totally removed except on specified post types

Comment: As said in my answer, use the *original* `wpse_67108_autplay_music()` code **in the question**, but change the only `is_singular()` there to `is_singular( 'your_post_type' )`. Note though, if you have a new requirement, please post a separate question for that. :)